# How to check if the cursor is at blank line in a textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I tried the following code to find an empty (or blank) line in a textbox but I don't know how to find the first `newline` before the caret position. How can I solve this? Or is there any shorter solution?

```
int i = textBox1.SelectionStart;
var endOfLine = textBox1.Text.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine,i);

 /* the next line should find the first occurance 
   of newline before the i postion, which method does that? */
var beginOfLine = textBox1.Text.XXX(Environment.NewLine,i); 

bool isEmpty = textBox1.Text.Substring(
                   beginOfLine,
                   endOfLine-beginofLine).Trim() == "";
```

Comment: Can you not use `string.IndexOf('\n', i);`?

Comment: I used it to find the end of line but how to find the start of line?

Comment: If you need to find the start you can use `string.LastIndexOf()` as in Bradleys answer below. This will work backwards from `i` until it finds a `\n`. Though presumably wont find anything if you're on the very first line.

Comment: embarrassing, thank you, I thought it searches from the end of string to the i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this overload of `String.LastIndexOf` to find the last index of a string before a specific index.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tw91fa3(v=vs.110).aspx

The line from your code you are looking for would be:

```
var begin = textBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine,i);
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the first occurrence of a newline character before `i`. Not the last. `"the line above needs a method to find the first occurance 
   of newline before the i postion"`

Comment: Yes I need first before i position, actually searching in backward

Comment: I interpreted that to mean "First occurrence starting from `i` and working backwards. Which seems to work with the general algorithm he posted.

Comment: So My answer is actually correct? You want the first occurrence searching backwards from `i`?

Comment: but i think it gives me the last index of Newline for the string after i, searches backward but from the end of string to i;

Comment: No, it starts at index `i` and heads to the start of the string. From MSDN: "Reports the zero-based index position of the last occurrence of a specified Unicode character within this instance. The search starts at a specified character position and proceeds backward toward the beginning of the string."

Comment: But you know what if its the first line of text?

Comment: I returns -1 if the pattern wasn't found.  You can just trigger off that return value and assume a blank line.

Answer (score 1):

In order for a line to be empty, the cursor position must either be at the beginning of the text or a NewLine must precede it AND the cursor position must be at the end of text or it must be followed by NewLine:

```
string s = textBox1.Text;
int i = textBox1.SelectionStart;

string start = s.Substring(0, i).TrimEnd(' ', '\t');
string end = s.Substring(i, s.Length - i).TrimStart(' ', '\t');
bool isEmpty = (start.Length == 0 || start.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine)) &&
               (end.Length == 0 || end.StartsWith(Environment.NewLine));
```

In order to deal with spaces and tab, they are trimmed from the start and the end. Note that I specified the characters to be trimmed explicitly, otherwise CRs and LFs would be trimmed as well. Note that there are a lot of white space characters, see [Char.IsWhiteSpace Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Are you sure in Windows if text be pasted from any source the new line is "\r\n"?

Comment: to make it shorter you can use variable i instead of textbox.SelectionStart

Comment: If text with lonely LFs or CRs are pasted into the TextBox, it will not display linebreaks. The text appers a it would be on a single line. But the questions is, how do you want to handle such cases anyway? Maybe it is best to fix them in the TextChanged event.

Comment: right, but it doesn't work, Moreover sorry but I must clarify by empty line I mean a line without text, it can have some spaces

Comment: I corrected my answer. The index `s[i + 1]` should be `s[i]`.

Comment: Yes I added it now, but empty line could mean that too, and I used Trim in my code for that reason, sorry, but I check your solution

Comment: I revised my solution completely in order to take account of spaces and tabs.

Comment: Thank you the code works too, I also added my solution in the answers I yet must decide which is better ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can check which line the caret is on and see if it's empty:

```
if ((tBox.Lines.Length == 0 && tBox.Text.Trim() == "") ||
   (tBox.Lines[tBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(tBox.SelectionStart)].Trim() == "")) {
  // caret is on an empty line
}
```

Comment: @Ahmad Missed the part about spaces.  Updated the post.

Comment: It is my test code, isEmpty = ((textBox1.Lines.Length == 0 && textBox1.Text.Trim() == "") ||
   (textBox1.Lines[textBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(textBox1.SelectionStart)].Trim() == ""));
            MessageBox.Show(isEmpty + "");

Comment: And again it shows False on empty lies, plus in the text it hasn't a constant behaviour (sometimes true sometiems false)

Comment: @Ahmad Not sure where the disconnect is.  I'm getting the opposite: True on empty lines.  This code isn't going to be inconsistent, so if you are getting sometimes true, sometimes false, something else is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Find the indexes of NewLine before and after the cursor position if the string in middle is Empty then the line is empty, for the first and last lines where the index of NewLine is -1, use 0 and string.length in place of them

```
   int i = textBox1.SelectionStart;
   var s = textBox1.Text;

   var start = s.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine, i);  
   var end = s.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine, i);

   start = start >= 0 ? start : 0;
   end = end >= 0 ? end : s.Length;

   bool isEmpty = s.Substring(start, end - start).Trim(' ', '\t') == "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt, assuming TextBox line endings are \r\n.

```
private static bool IsCursorOnEmptyLine(TextBox targetTextBox)
{
    var cursorPosition = targetTextBox.SelectionStart;
    var positionBefore = targetTextBox.Text.LastIndexOf('\n', cursorPosition == 0 ? 0 : cursorPosition - 1);
    var positionAfter  = targetTextBox.Text.IndexOf('\r', cursorPosition);
    if (positionBefore == -1) positionBefore = 0;
    if (positionAfter  == -1) positionAfter  = targetTextBox.Text.Length;
    return targetTextBox.Text.Substring(positionBefore, positionAfter - positionBefore).Trim() == "";
}
```

Example usage:

```
Debug.Print("Empty Line: " + (IsCursorOnEmptyLine(myTextBox) ? "Yes" : "No"));
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer, before you posted a working answer and you soon deleted it, I guess this new answer works but its very similar mine

Comment: NP, my first answer was for pure empty lines, but saw the update that empty should include spaces, so deleted my answer as I had other stuff to do. However it was an interesting question, so wanted to code something and see how it compared to other peoples methods :)

Comment: Please vote the question, if you found it interesting, I need up-votes to leave a ban

Comment: Already did the day you posted to cancel out a down vote, hate how a lot of questions get down voted without giving a reason.

Answer (score 0):

First get the text prior to your cursor:

```
string textPriorToCursor = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, textBox1.Text.Length - i);
```

Then get the last occurrence of a new line in the text prior to the cursor:

```
var begin = textPriorToCursor.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine);
```

Combining the above two lines into one would look like this:

```
var begin = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, textBox1.Text.Length - i).LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Please vote the question, if you found it interesting, I need up-votes to leave a ban